# json to select option jquery

Tags: jquery, json

when i try to parsing my json data... i get this...

```
[object object],[object object],[object object]....
```

My code is like this...

```
var json
            function go(){
                json = jQuery.parseJSON($('#json').val());
                alert(json);

            }
```

And my json is look like this...

```
[{"Jenis Bahan":"sp100roll","Lebar":"160","Harga / Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis Bahan":"sp100ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga / Meter":"5300"},{"Jenis Bahan":"sp75ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga / Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis Bahan":"sp75roll","Lebar":"160","Harga / Meter":"3800"},{"Jenis Bahan":"sp50roll","Lebar":"160","Harga / Meter":"2800"},{"Jenis Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga / Meter":"c"},{"Jenis Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga / Meter":"c"},{"Jenis Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga / Meter":"c"}]
```

And my question is.. how to get a alert result like this...

```
Name = sp100roll value = 160-4300
Name = sp75ecer value= 160-5300
......
```

But the final is.. i would like to create a select box option from it.. so it would be like this...

```
<option value="160-4300">sp100roll</option>
<option value="160-5300">sp75ecer</option>
and etc...
```

Any one can help?

i already try many answer but still didnt work..

Answer (score 2):

Don't use alerts to see the contents of variable use `console.log`. This will show you all the elements in your array and all the properties in the objects in the console, rather than just trying to convert it to a string like with `alert`.

```
json = jQuery.parseJSON($('#json').val());
console.log(json);
//console.dir(json);//for IE
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/zA54W/

For building the select just iterate through the array and set the values and text fron each object

```
...
$('#theselect').append('<option value="'+json[i]['Lebar']+'-'+json[i]['Harga / Meter']+
'">'+json[i]['Jenis Bahan']+'</option>');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That you json looks a bit problem，when you write like this:"Jenis Bahan":"sp100roll",it's equivalent to:var Jenis Bahan="sp100roll"；So that the definition of variables is not consistent with the rules，you can change the json like this:[{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp100roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp100ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"5300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp75ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp75roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"3800"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp50roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"2800"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"}]
Now you can read it like this:
function go(){
                var data=[{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp100roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp100ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"5300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp75ecer","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"4300"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp75roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"3800"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"sp50roll","Lebar":"160","Harga_Meter":"2800"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"},{"Jenis_Bahan":"a","Lebar":"b","Harga_Meter":"c"}];
                for(var i=0;i

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify instead of parseJSON. That might help